# Typedef and struct in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Is there any difference between those two:

```
typedef struct ddwq{
    int b;
}ta;

typedef struct {
    int b;
}ta;
```

Comment: Some old debuggers had trouble with anonymous structures, so it helped to have a tag, even if the code never used the tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the former case, you can reference the type of the struct as either `struct ddwq` or `ta`.  In the latter case, you can *only* reference it as `ta` since the struct has no tag.

The first case is required if the struct will contain a pointer to itself such as:

```
typedef struct ddwq{
    int b;
    struct ddwq *p;
}ta;
```

The type name `ta` isn't visible inside of the struct, so the struct must have a tag name for it to reference itself.